# Tkinter window on Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, filedialog

i'm working with the Tk module, to select files and get their path. After selecting file the Tk window doesn't close. It remains open even the code is over.

Before saying creating this post, i tried to put different solution(No duplicate):root.destroy();root.withdraw();root.quit()

But it doesn't works.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import Tk


def get_path():

    root = Tk()
    root.filename =  filedialog.askopenfilenames()
    return (root.filename)
    root.quit()

e=get_path()
print(e)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVzHf.png)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You have to call `root.quit()` _before_ returning from the function...

Comment: It worked with root.destroy() and root.withdraw before returning.
Thanks

Comment: `.quit()` does not destroy the main window, it only stops `mainoop`. To destroy a window, call `.destroy()` on that window

Answer (score 0):

"askopenfilename" is used to get "files" only, such as .py, .txt, .odt files etc. So, the window will close if you selected a file.

Whereas, if you want to get the path to a "directory", use "askdirectory" :

```
import tkinter as tk    
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.filename =  filedialog.askdirectory()
return (root.filename)
root.quit()
```